# Create Metadata from powershell scripts in Bamboo

Tags: powershell, bamboo

In My bamboo plan, i have a step to run build.ps1 file that generates unique version using gitversion and updates it to all assemblies.

I wanted to create a metadata in bamboo to store this version information , so that it can be easily viewed.

Otherwise, I have to download the logs to see the version generated while executing powershell build script.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using this plugin to update a global variable that stores the version metadata: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.variable.updater.variable-updater-generic/server/overview